# Create a 4-ary recursive directory tree of given depth using c++

Tags: c++, directory

Say my directory is C:/temp,

Given depth of 2, I want to create folder in following fashion :

`temp/a temp/b temp/c temp/d`    ---- depth 1

```
temp/a/a temp/a/b temp/a/c temp/a/d    
temp/b/a temp/b/b temp/b/c temp/b/d        depth 2
temp/c/a temp/c/b temp/c/d temp/c/d
temp/d/a temp/d/b temp/d/c temp/d/d
```

Can this be done efficiently using boost libraries?After recursively creating how do I keep track of the depth?Can the concept of n-ary trees be applied here?This needs to be done for a production code hence the depth can go till even 100

Comment: You don't need Boost to do this, just some recursive code that tracks the depth

Comment: i am unable to apply the concept of recursion in windows folders .Need some hints

Comment: `4**100` is around `10**60`